# Privacy Crawler

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler

i need your help, can anyone explain me why my code doesnt find the a-tag privacy on the site zoho.com?

my code finds the link "privacy" on other sites well but not on the site zoho.com

I use symfony Crawler: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

```
// Imprint Check //

function findPrivacy($domain) {

 $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13';
 $curl = curl_init($domain);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
 $data = curl_exec($curl);

 $crawler = new Crawler($data);

 $nodeValues = $crawler->filter('a')->each(function ($node) {

     if(str_contains($node->attr('href'), 'privacy-police') || str_contains($node->attr('href'), 'privacy')) {
         
         return true;

     } else {
         
         return false;

     }

 });

 return $nodeValues;
 
}
```

if you watch the source code from zoho.com, then you will see the footer is empty. But on the site, the footer isnt empty if you scroll down.

How can I find now this link Privacy?

Comment: privacy-police? besides the footer and much of the content is added by js (which php wont render) in this file https://www.zohowebstatic.com/sites/all/themes/zoho/scripts/zohocustom.js use puppeteer to do your scraping instead

Comment: [Symfony panther](https://github.com/symfony/panther) has the same interface as `DomCrawler` but runs a full-fledged browser via WebDriver that can run javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script cannot find what is not there. If you load the zoho.com page in a browser and look at the source code, you will notice that the word privacy is not even present. It's possible that the footer containing the link to the privacy policy is loaded asynchronously, which PHP cannot handle.

EDIT: by asynchronously loaded I mean using something like AJAX, which is client-side only. Since PHP is server-side only, it cannot perform the operations required to load the footer containing the link to the privacy policy.